# Building E learning courses

Tags: scorm1.2

I have to build some e learning courses for my project. I have already tried articulate storyline and easygenerator. Can I have some suggestions on other authoring tools that I can use freely to build clean e learning courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Articulate Storyline is the best tool ever for building responsive elearning courses.

Along with Adobe Captivate and easygenerator are good tools for this purpose.

Adapt Learning is a new framework to publish web based interactive courses.

My personal suggestion is "Articulate Storyline 2" and it is based on the fact "Chose the software/ tool which have maximum online help by forums / blogs / and other resources"
and my experience is that Articulate storyline has greater online help than others.

you can find this also helpful 
http://elearningindustry.com/the-ultimate-list-of-html5-elearning-authoring-tools